# How to perform SUM and count in NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the below POCO

```
public class Collection
    {        
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        public string AccountId { get; set; }

        public string ReceiptId { get; set; }

    }
```

I am looking for

*a) SUM Of Amount 
b) Count Of ReceiptId*

**group by AccountId** using Nest.

since I am new to Elastic Search and Nest, I am having difficulty to build the query.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
 var result = ConnectionToES.EsClient().Search<Collection>(s => s
                    .Index("collections")
                    .Aggregations(a => a

                        .Terms("ReceiptId", ts => ts
                            .Field(o => o.AccountId)
                            .Aggregations(aa => aa.Sum("Amount", sa => sa.Field(o => Convert.ToDecimal(o.Amount)))

                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
```

But when I do the same using LINQ, it works

```
var res = ConnectionToES.EsClient().Search<Collection>(s => s
            .Index("collections")
            .From(0)
            .Size(1000)
            .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));

            List<Collection> objCollection = new List<Collection>();

            foreach (var hit in res.Hits)
            {
                objCollection.Add(
                    new Collection
                    {
                        Id = hit.Source.Id.ToString()
                         ,

                        Amount = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hit.Source.Amount.ToString()) ? "0" : hit.Source.Amount.ToString()
                         ,
                        AccountId = hit.Source.AccountId.ToString()
                         ,
                        ReceiptId = hit.Source.ReceiptId.ToString()

                         ,
                        CollectorId = hit.Source.CollectorId.ToString()
                         ,
                        CollectionDate = hit.Source.CollectionDate.ToString()

                    });
            }

            var aggrResult = objCollection.GroupBy(t => t.AccountId)
                           .Select(t => new
                           {
                               AccountNumber = t.Key,
                               Count = t.Count(),
                               Amount = t.Sum(item => Convert.ToDouble(item.Amount)),
                           }).ToList();
```

I want to do the same aggregation in an ES way.

Comment: What you want : .GroupBy(x => x.AccountId)
.Select(x => new { id = x.AccountId, count = x.Count(), total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount)})
.ToList();

Comment: yes but in the Elastic Search /NEST style. Sir, I would like to perform the aggregation in the Elastic Search using NEST

Comment: Hello, please Share es mappings. Note that es fields are case sensitive, if you automap i thinck es create a "receiptId" field, not a "ReceiptId".
Also you have to change your mappings as said bellow, and index the field Amount  as a numeric value (the aggregation is made on es side, Convert.ToDecimal( has a nosense in your exemple).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers to help

1. `Amount` should be a numeric value (perhaps `double`?) in order to perform a sum aggregation on it.
2. The terms aggregation on `AccountId` looks like it should be `ReceiptId` to bucket by values of `ReceiptId`. Also, if `ReceiptId` is a string value that does not need full-text search, it should be mapped as a `keyword` datatype, which will allow aggregations, sorting, and term level queries.

Comment: I have tried as suggested . May be i am missing something. I've updated the question.Please help

Comment: OK, I misread your question. Counting `ReceiptId` is the same as the count of documents in each bucket when grouped by `AccountId` - is that what you want? If it is, the document count is already computed for each bucket. For reading aggregations and sub-aggregations, take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#handling-aggregate-response